# promise doesn't get rejected

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have created a **promise** that it's task is to ensure that **specific** tag **exists** on the page

and it is **resolved** only when tag **exist** => `this work perfectly`

and after 5 seconds if the tag **don't** get found it will be **rejected** => `this part don't work`

and after more that 5 seconds it doesn't get **rejected** !

this is my code , based on **Jquery**

```
function findCal() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let flag = true
    const time0 = new Date().getTime() / 1000

    do {
      if ($('.ng-star-inserted .dp-material').length > 0) {
        flag = false
        res()
      }
      const time1 = new Date().getTime() / 1000
      console.log('time', time1 - time0)
      if (time1 - time0 > 5) {
        rej('Time out ; Please try again')

      }

    } while (flag)
  })
}


try {
  await findCal()

} catch (err) {

  alert(err)
}
```

**Why** promise reject don't work ?

Comment: You may have an infinite loop. Notice how you don't terminate the loop when you reject. Promises process asynchronously and won't be able to trigger until then callstack is clear. You can break the loop and therefore clear the call stack by setting the flag on rejection too.

Comment: Also, I really think `do...while` is discouraged. Plus, you should really just use an `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000))` instead, because this loop _will_ hang your application.

Comment: Promises represent the result of an asynchronous action - they don't cause parallelism and your code runs synchronously from start to finish. Since it never finishes it never exits the loop. Try adding a `return` or a `break` when you call `rej`

Comment: @somethinghere I don't think there is anything wrong with do/while here in particular - this would be the same error with a `for` or a `while` or `for... of` with an infinite iterable etc.

Comment: Out of curiosity: are you trying to wait for an element to be appended to the DOM before continuing? If so, then the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) might be a good technique to accomplish this without having to poll.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier exactly , i am trying to wait for an element to append and then continue .

Comment: while loop is the wrong solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

With the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) you can monitor any changes in DOM structure. In your case you want to know whenever a specific `Node` is added to the DOM.

In the snippet below we observe the `<body>` tag and all it's children for any changes. If you do know the container your target element is going to be in, then you could change the observed element to that container.

With `setTimeout` we wait 5 seconds before the `Promise` is rejected.

```
function findCal() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      for (const { addedNodes } of mutations) {
        for (const node of addedNodes) {
          if (node.className === 'ng-star-inserted dp-material') {
            resolve();
          }
        }
      }
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
      subtree: true,
      childList: true
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.disconnect();
      reject();
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

The function can be used in the same manner as you already implemented.